# How can I reset only Y-axis/X-axis in OxyPlot

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I am using OxyPlot for WPF. There is a function ResetAllAxes() which resets both axes. How can I reset only X or Y axis? Thanks

Comment: Could we some of your source code posted , that would really help us help you better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all the axes from your plot model, then call the reset method on the axis you want. It helps if you set the key when you create the axis.

```
            var axis = PlotModel.Axes.First(x => x.Key.Equals("AxisKey"));
            axis.Reset();
```